# Finding the inverse function of a quadratic function

Tags: functions, relations, conic-sections

let $f:[-4,∞) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} , f(x)=-(x+4)^2 +3$. show that $f^{-1}:(-∞,3] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{3-x}-4.$

a question from my 11th-grade maths assignment. I don't even know where to start. please help.

Comment: Please use Mathjax.

Comment: It's the inverse function, not the reciprocal.

Comment: @LeAnhDung will use in future, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow this procedure when trying to calculate inverse functions:

**STEP 1:**

Write the initial function

$$
f(x) = -(x+4)^2+3
$$

as

$$
y = -(x+4)^2+3
$$

**STEP 2:**

Replace $y$ with $x$ like so

$$
x=-(y+4)^2+3
$$

**STEP 3:**

Solve the above in order to separate $y$

$$
\sqrt{3-x} -4 = y
$$

**STEP 4:**

Replace this new $y$ with $f^{-1}(x)$

$$
\sqrt{3-x} -4 = f^{-1}(x)
$$

Find the domain of this new function. Can you proceed?

***STEP 5:***

Check your work knowing that $$f^{-1}(f(x))=x$$

If you do some algebra, verify that your result (in this case)

$$
f^{-1}(f(x)) = \sqrt{3-f(x)} -4 = \sqrt{3-(-(x+4)^2+3)} -4 = x
$$

Comment: Good and clear. One more step, is to prove that the inverse function found is indeed the correct function (optional).

Comment: thank you. As for the domain restriction, that is only found by graphing the inverse function?

Comment: @chloerogers you can find the domain by basically identifying what values of $x$ are not allowed (because of the square root in this case). so in this case, $x$ cannot be greater than 3 for the function to be real

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For $x\ge-4$, solve the equation $-(x+4)^2+3=y$ and find $x$ in term of $y$.